only one top level element is allowed in xml
<!-- BaseBuildingPlus -->
   <type name="BBP_T1_WallKit">
        <lifetime>7200</lifetime>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>
    </type>
    <type name="BBP_T2_WallKit">
        <lifetime>7200</lifetime>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>

is the code that we are using and getting the only top level element is allowed the rest of the xml is formatted just like the code above

What is the question, Jimmy?

A well formed xml has only one root tag.  You have an array at the root which sometimes is called fragmented.  So libraries have special settings to allow reading fragments.  I do not know what libraries you are using to give a answer.
